# Instantiating a class - Python

Tags: python, class, object, attributeerror

I'm trying to instantiate a straightforward class in Python.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age, major, gpa):
        name = self.name
        age = self.age
        major = self.major
        gpa = self.gpa


def main():
    student_1 = Student('John', 31, 'History', 3.4)
    student_2 = Student('George', 31, 'English', 3.5)
    print student_1.name, student_2.name
```

The error I get is:

> AttributeError: Student instance has no attribute 'name'

Comment: self.name = name and so on, you have inverted variable assigments

Comment: You have your assignment statement reversed. It should be `self.name = name`.

Comment: *facepalm*... thanks everyone

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
    name = self.name
    age = self.age
    major = self.major
    gpa = self.gpa
```

to:

```
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.major = major
    self.gpa = gpa
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting this error because you are accessing attributes before defining them. That's because you have your assignments the wrong way - you're attempting to assign the (undefined) attributes to the arguments instead of the other way round:

```
def __init__(self, name, age, major, gpa):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.major = major
    self.gpa = gpa
```